# How to put 2 layers to follow same bezierpath without one hiding the other

Tags: ios, calayer, uibezierpath

I have created 2 CALayers of same size and am passing these to the method below. However, the two layers runs together.  How can I seperate these so that both are visible?

```
- (void) myAnimation : (CALayer *) sublayer {
    UIBezierPath* aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:CGRectMake(30, 100, 270, 270)];

    CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    anim.path = aPath.CGPath;
    anim.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;
    anim.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    anim.duration =35.0;
    [sublayer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"race"];
}
```

Comment: Have you tried giving them a different `beginTime`?

Comment: have a delay between two method calls with those layers.

Comment: How about having different colors for each and making each path a bit translucent? And how about having different stroke widths for each path?

Comment: Thanks, David.  beginTime did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Your path begins and ends at the same point. Assuming both beginning times are the same and duration is the same, your layers will precisely overlap. You can either shift the beginning time or rotate your `UIBezierPath* aPath` Here's an example of rotating your `UIBezierPath* aPath` and altering the duration. It should give you an idea how you could alter duration, begin time, rotation, etc.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    CALayer * layer1 = [CALayer layer];
    CALayer * layer2 = [CALayer layer];
    [layer1 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 50)];
    [layer2 setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 5, 100)];
    layer1.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:.1 green:.5 blue:1 alpha:.35] CGColor];
    layer2.backgroundColor = [[UIColor colorWithRed:.9 green:.2 blue:.5 alpha:.35] CGColor];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer1];
    [self.view.layer addSublayer:layer2];
    [self myAnimation:layer1 andRotation:0 andDuration:35.0];
    [self myAnimation:layer2 andRotation:10 andDuration:10.0];
}
- (void) myAnimation:(CALayer *)sublayer andRotation:(CGFloat)rot andDuration:(CFTimeInterval)dur {
    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(30, 100, 270, 270);
    UIBezierPath* aPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithOvalInRect:rect];
    // Creating a center point around which we will transform the path
    CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(rect), CGRectGetMidY(rect));
    CGAffineTransform transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, center.x, center.y);
    transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, rot);
    // Recenter the transform
    transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(transform, -center.x, -center.y);
    // This is the new path we will use.
    CGPathRef rotated =  CGPathCreateCopyByTransformingPath(aPath.CGPath, &transform);
    CAKeyframeAnimation *anim = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
    anim.path = rotated;
    anim.rotationMode = kCAAnimationRotateAuto;
    anim.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    anim.duration =dur;
    [sublayer addAnimation:anim forKey:@"race"];
}
```